# How to put AdView in ConstraintLayout at bottom and below other stuff?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to migrate from RelativeLayout to ConstraintLayout but I'm having problems adding the AdMob AdView to the bottom and the rest of the content above it. For example, using RelativeLayout was that simple. You only need to put `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` on the AdView and `android:layout_above="@+id/adView"` on the view which is containing the stuff.

I'm trying to understand how to migrate this sample code and these two lines of code to the equivalent using a ConstraintLayout instead of a RelativeLayout.

Please, can someone help me with this migration?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView"/>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_id_banner">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I tested using `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/adView"` on the stuff i want above the adView and `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` on the adView but it's not working because the stuff is not above the adView it's behind. And Also the adView is not centered. It's very frustrating.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

First, I want to talk about two pieces of behavior that are unique to `ConstraintLayout` and that aren't necessarily obvious when you first pick it up.

**`match_parent` is not supported**

This detail is tucked away in a one-liner in the developer guide: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

> **Note**: You cannot use `match_parent` for any view in a `ConstraintLayout`. Instead use "match constraints" (`0dp`).

To get "match parent" behavior, combine a `0dp` dimension with constraints for both corresponding edges of your view:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
```

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

**Margins are only enforced if they have a corresponding constraint**

Just adding `android:layout_marginTop` will not do anything unless that view also has a top constraint, like `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf` or `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf`.

**Your specific issue**

Here's the updated layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/adView"/>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:adSize="BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="@string/ad_id_banner"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

To achieve the horizontal centering of the `AdView`, we constrain the left and right edges to the parent's left and right edges. This "pulls" the `AdView` equally from each side, centering it. To get it to stick to the bottom of the screen, we constrain its bottom edge to the bottom of the parent.

As for the `LinearLayout`, first we change its dimensions both to `0dp`. This will let the constraints define its size. Then we constrain the top, left, and right edges to the top, left, and right edges of the parent. We constrain the bottom edge to the top edge of the `AdView`. This causes it to fill the screen horizontally, and fill all of the vertical space the `AdView` isn't using.

Finally, we change the top margin on the `AdView` into a bottom margin on the `LinearLayout`. This is because the `LinearLayout`'s bottom edge is constrained to the `AdView`'s top edge (but the `AdView`'s top edge isn't constrained to the `LinearLayout`'s bottom edge, so top margin would have no effect).

Comment: thank you so much for your great answer, my problem was that i wasn't doing  android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp" but your answer is perfect and made me understand this a lot more than before. :)