# Positioning AdView at the bottom of fragment (ConstraintLayout + NestedScrollView)

Tags: android, android-xml

I'm just a bit confused on why the smart banner isn't fixed so that it is on the bottom of the fragments.

The first fragment (tab1) doesn't have a NestedScrollView, the second one does. However in neither of those fragments my code seems to be right.

I used the top answer of that post to position my AdView: [How to put AdView in ConstraintLayout at bottom and below other stuff?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49137449/how-to-put-adview-in-constraintlayout-at-bottom-and-below-other-stuff)

tab1 (shortened)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"                android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/adView"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"/>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
```

tab2 (shortened)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="700dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/adView2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"/>


    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

That's how it currently looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwc2M.jpg

**edit**
Problem seems to be with the toolbar and the layout.

activity_main

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="de.h0a.havin.zeugnisoberstufe.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabBackground="@color/colorPrimary" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Any reasons made you using ConstraintLayout, if no, use RelativeLayout instead

Comment: Please post the xml of host activity

Comment: @HaiHack ConstaintLayout seems to be the recommended one so I choose that. Also I added the other xml. I think you might spot whats wrong there.